# Android Studio 1.4.1 rendering problems

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio 1.4.1 and every time when I create a new project I have a rendering problem "Missing styles. is the correct theme chosen for this layout". I have tried to choose different API but the problem remains.

Also attache the screenshot of error
[rendering problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kal6o.jpg)

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you click the "Automatically add all missing attributes"?

Comment: I can't click the "Automatically add all missing attributes" because it unclickable.

Comment: try to change ur theme from the preview section to holo theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio is often brain-dead when it comes to matching up with the Android SDK installed. It generates code and app styles that assume a particular SDK release that might not be installed. The latest version of Android Studio always assumes you have the latest SDKs..

Open up Android SDK Manager (from the menu: `Tools->Android->Sdk Manager` ) and get the latest SDKs, platform, and build tools.  Then restart Android Studio and create a new project.   Then make sure Android Studio is configured to use the latest for your tools for your new project. (File->Project Structure)

And if that doesn't work, then blow off the whole thing.  I had to do this a lot when I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio.

1. Uninstall Android Studio and Android SDK
2. Delete the directories from which they were installed.
3. Delete the .gradle, .android, and .AndroidStudio1.4 directories from your home directory (or c:\users\yourname directory).
4. Download latest Android Studio and re-install. Don't import any settings.
5. First run of Android Studio should force it to update any missing SDK dependencies.
6. Create new project. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

**first  go to styles and and paste the  below code to all the style files**

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

**or**

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```